# Apache find the sender of get request

Tags: apache, http, get

What's the easiest way to find the sender of a get request from apache? I keep seeing error logs that imply some page/application is sending a get request for a favicon file, which is nonexistent. I grep'd my entire webhost directory but not a single file in there is referencing this nonexistent favicon file.

Is there a way to find out exactly what or who is sending the get request for this file?

Apache 2 on CentOs.

Comment: Google for favicon.ico, there's not much you can do to prevent browsers requesting it.

Comment: So favicon files are requested even if I don't specify the <link> tag for them?

Comment: Yes. The <link> tag is only important, if you like to name them other than favicon.ico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, most modern browsers request favicon files regardless.